# CodeIgniter production deployment error 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I finished my CodeIgniter application, managed to deploy it to shared hosting, but I'm getting error 404 and a warning.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /data/web/virtuals/53627/virtual/www/application/config/config.php:1)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 568

Backtrace:

File: /data/web/virtuals/53627/virtual/www/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

I've only had this issue since I switched to Codeigniter 3.0. When I deploy my site with CodeIgniter 2.2.0. Any idea what might be the cause? I'm getting this error regardless of using .htacess. If it help, here is a link to the [site](http://www.mtbbazar.cz/index.php/).

Comment: First double check all models and controllers first letter upper case example Welcome.php and not welcome.php